# Accessing Visual Cobol from C#

Tags: c#, com, cobol, microfocus

We are using Micro Focus Visual Cobol 2.1 in Visual Studio 2010. (Note this is not Cobol.Net)

We would like to access the functionality in Cobol from a C# program.

We had hoped to be able to generate a COM wrapper and call the Cobol code through the COM wrapper, but cannot find the setting to create the COM wrapper.

Anyone know how we can access the Cobol code from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out Micro Focus's own Visual COBOL site, and it's Visual Cobol forum. There are relevant articles and Q&A - http://community.microfocus.com/microfocus/cobol/

Answer (score 1):

AcuCobol's Extend Cobol (which was bought out by MicroFocus) had C routines that you could compile into a C program to call Cobol programs. You might want to ask you MicroFocus Sales/Support to find out what they can do for you.